# GCM messages are not received with android app at all

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have an old problem: I cannot receive GCM messages with android app. According to the server log they are succesfully delivered to the GCM server and are sent further, but my client side app doesn't seem to have received them.

This is the GCM-relevant fragment of my manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />


<!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

<!-- This app has permission to register and receive data message. -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />


<permission
    android:name="my.package.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="my.package.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />


<receiver
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
    <intent-filter>

        <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.GCM_RECEIVED_ACTION" />

        <category android:name="my.package" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

<service android:name=".GcmIntentService" />
```

This is my service-class GcmIntentService:

```
public class GcmIntentService extends GcmListenerService {

private String TAG = "myReceiver";
@Override
public  void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {

    Log.d(TAG, "message received");//this log is never shown
    if (!data.isEmpty()) { 
         Log.d(TAG, "interesting message receiver");
    }        
}
}
```

This is my project build.gradle dependency:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.3.0-beta1'
```

I think I forgot to add something, that's why it doesn't work at all. I tried with WLAN and SIM-card internet. so the promblem is not in internet firewall. Sender API and GCM-token seem to be correct (they were copied and pasted from the corresponding settings of the developer account).

Thank you for your help in advance.

Edit: see the answer below

Comment: Have you put right Project ID(Sender Id) in Android app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do following changes in manifest

Replace following code

```
<service android:name=".GcmIntentService" />
```

with

```
<service
            android:name="packagename.MyGcmListenerService"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

and in

```
<uses-permission android:name="your.package.name.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

write whatever youer packagename is in place of 
"your.package.name"

Comment: I changed my service declaration and replaced with the name of my package. But it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

A few things are wrong / might be wrong. You need the sender id in the gcm registration code of the main activity.And you have 3 times the `C2D_MESSAGE` permission, which is the first time wrong (`put.your.package.name`). The second time it is correct for the production stage but will not work for development, and the third time you have the permission correct for development.

You should only have it once.

And indeed like @Android india suggests change your service declaration in the manifest.

Comment: yes, really, you are write. but the removing of wrong line doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

Please see this

your receiver declaration has some bug

```
 <receiver
        android:name="yourpackage.receiver.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>

            <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="yourpackage" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: What bug do you mean?

Comment: I user now this class com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver instead of GcmBroadcastReceiver.

Comment: the manifest code which you put in question does not have category

Comment: Have you seen this line? `<category android:name="my.package" />`

Answer (score 0):

Android Manifest fragment that works:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />   

<!-- This app has permission to register and receive data message. -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />


<permission
    android:name="my.package.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="my.package.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

```
    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="my.package" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service
        android:name="my.package.GcmListener"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
</application>
```